# SemgrexPattern lemma attribute doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, nlp, pattern-matching, stanford-nlp

Here is a very simple example using `SemgrexPattern` from Stanford NLP.
I do not understand why it doesn't find any matches with `{lemma:/eat/}` while it finds a match with `{word:/eats/}`. I used the `LemmaAnnotation` class to get the lemma of the verb "to eat" and it's "eat".

Thank you for your help :)

```
package Project;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.TreebankLangParserParams;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.EnglishTreebankParserParams;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.semgrex.SemgrexMatcher;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.semgrex.SemgrexPattern;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructureFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;

public class SemgrexDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String treeString = "(ROOT (S (NP (NNP John)) (VP (VBZ eats) (NP (NN pizza))) (. .)))";
    Tree tree = Tree.valueOf(treeString);
    SemanticGraph graph = SemanticGraphFactory.generateUncollapsedDependencies(tree);
    TreebankLangParserParams params = new EnglishTreebankParserParams();
    GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = params.treebankLanguagePack().grammaticalStructureFactory(params.treebankLanguagePack().punctuationWordRejectFilter(), params.typedDependencyHeadFinder());
    GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(tree);
    System.err.println(graph);
    SemgrexPattern semgrex = SemgrexPattern.compile("{}=A <<dobj=reln {lemma:/eat/}=B");
    SemgrexMatcher matcher = semgrex.matcher(graph);
    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.err.println(matcher.getNode("A") + " <<dobj " + matcher.getNode("B"));
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lemmata are not added automatically to the tokens when you parse a tree string to a Tree object, so the lemma attribute of all the nodes in the `SemanticGraph` is `null` and therefore `{lemma:/eat/}` doesn't match any node.

You can add the lemmata using the `lemma(String word, String pos)` method of the `Morphology` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  String treeString = "(ROOT (S (NP (NNP John)) (VP (VBZ eats) (NP (NN pizza))) (. .)))";
  Tree tree = Tree.valueOf(treeString);
  SemanticGraph graph = SemanticGraphFactory.generateUncollapsedDependencies(tree);

  //add lemmata
  Morphology morphology = new Morphology();
  for (IndexedWord node : graph.vertexSet()) {
    String lemma = morphology.lemma(node.word(), node.tag());
    node.setLemma(lemma);
  }

  System.err.println(graph);
  SemgrexPattern semgrex = SemgrexPattern.compile("{}=A <<dobj=reln {lemma:/eat/}=B");
  SemgrexMatcher matcher = semgrex.matcher(graph);
  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.err.println(matcher.getNode("A") + " <<dobj " + matcher.getNode("B"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see !! Thank you for taking the time to answer me :)